# ¿Como puedo compilar mi codigo php?

Tags: php, compilar

no se de que manera puedo ejecutar mi codigo php, estuve investigando y encontre que con algo que se llama xampp, ya puse mi codigo en la carpeta de htdocs, esta es la ubicacion exacta C:\xampp\htdocs\openwebinar_blog\ejemplo_fichero
Ya escribi en el navegador localhost\openwebinar_blog\ejemplo_fichero y no pasa nada.

Otra duda, si subo este codigo a una pagina en internet, puede guardar la foto en mi carpeta donde se supone que se deberian guardar?

Se llama index.php y este es el codigo

```
<?php

echo '<html><head></head><body>';
echo '<h1>Ejemplo subida de fichero</h1>';
echo '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
echo 'Fichero a recibir: <input type="file" name="myfile" /><br />';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Enviar">';
echo '</form>';

if ( isset( $_FILES ) && isset( $_FILES['myfile'] ) && !empty( $_FILES['myfile']['name'] && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])))


    if ( ! is_uploaded_file( $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'] ) ){
        echo "Error: El fichero encontrado no fue procesado por la subida correctamente";
        exit;
    }
$source = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$destination = __DIR__.'/upload/'.$_FILES['myfile']['name'];

if ( is_file($destination) ) {
    echo "Error: Ya existe almacenado un fichero con ese nombre";
    @unlink(ini_get('upload_tmp_dir').$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
    exit;
}

if ( ! @move_uploaded_file($source, $destination ) ) {
    echo "Error: No se ha podido mover el fichero enviado a la carpeta de destino";
    @unlink(ini_get('upload_tmp_dir').$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
    exit;
}
echo "Fichero subido correctamente a: ".$destination;
}
```

Comment: que código tienes ejecutando en esa ruta, tienes el archivo con extensión .php? y de ser posible muéstranos el código que llevas ahi

Comment: se llama index.php y este es el codigo

Comment: Compilar PHP? https://www.peachpie.io OJO, PHP es un lenguaje interpretado.

Comment: Mas biene ejectuar mi codigo en el navegador

Comment: PHP es un lenguaje que se ejecuta en el servidor, nunca en el navegador

Comment: @nauseantparrot como se ejecuta en el navegador?

Comment: No es posible hacer que corra en el navegador, es de servidor

Comment: oops, queria escribir servidor, como se ejecuta en el servidor? si subi este archivo a una pagina web es posible que funcione y las imagenes se guarden en mi computadora?

Comment: Podrías describir exactamente el inconveniente que presentas por favor